# Execute Java Method on receiving an email in outlook

Tags: swing, rest, vbscript, outlook, executable-jar

I have a `Swing` desktop application which needs to be updated periodically with details from `REST` response. Now the app needs to hit the `REST` url whenever there is an email received in an outlook folder(exchange server). I have the app packaged in a runnable jar file. App will always be running in the background.
Now I can't use `javamail` as it requires authentication in a plain file, which is not feasible for me due to security reasons.

I got another option which is to hook a `VBscript` to the outlook folder and then somehow run the Java method inside my swing application's code and update the `Swing` UI in background.

I'm not sure how can the `VBScript` be used to call a java method of a running app.

Anyone has an experience on any of the above option or has an alternate solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you poll the server periodically?

Comment: By server if you mean Exchange server then no I can't do that either.